# Can one recite havdalah during daytime?

Tags: havdalah

We know that havdalah is recited at the end of shabbat or festival at night. In some cases, such as if a person died on motzei shabbat, havdalah is delayed until the next day if the family can't say in at night.

Similarly, if one forgot havdala on motzei shabbat, it can be recited until Tuesday night.

In case of delayed havdala, can one recite it during daytime? Is the halacha the same for shabbat and festivals?

Comment: Is there anything missing from my answer or has it fully addressed your concerns?

Comment: of course thanks alot @ Double AA further Can you clear me as am getting some information that havdalah can be recited until thursday

Comment: The two opinions brought in Shulchan Arukh are noted in my answer. It could be someone argues, but I think the most popular opinion is the opinion until Tuesday night (ie half of the week).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Havdala can be recited during the daytime if it wasn't said on Saturday night. (See ShA OC 299:6 where the two opinions given for the latest time to make up Havdala are "all of Yom Rishon" (ie. Sunday until sunset) and "until the end of Yom Shelishi" (ie. Tuesday until sunset).)

However, the blessings on the spices and candle are only ever added on Saturday night itself (ibid.).

Comment: It might be helpful to add that the reasons the blessing for spice/candle are only added motzash is that (1) spices compensate for the neshama yeteira which leaves then and (2) candles because of the light of Adam harishon. Just a thought

Comment: @mbloch It's easier if people just realized those don't really have much to do with Havdala. Then I wouldn't have even had to include the caveat. What you listed are the reasons those things are done on motzash, not the reasons they are "only" done on motzash.